# Filtering SharePoint list item on version number

Tags: sharepoint, list, filtering

I need to filter a sharepoint list based upon the version number of the list items.
I only want to see items where the version number is say greater than 50.

When I apply such a filter to the list, the result is incorrect.

I get all items where the first digit of the version number is greater than the first digit of the filter value, so in this example any version starting with 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9.

What filter criteria should I be using to achieve the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like Sharepoint is storing the version number as a string.  What method are you using to "filter"?

Answer (score 0):

Have tried > 50 and also > "50" as the filtering criteria. Neither produces the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Post](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/09/working-with-versions-in-list.html)

It seems that the version id's start at 512 and increment by 512 for each version afterwards.  Have you tried to query off the VersionLabel?  It's a string.